# iOS Custom Framework - how to expose a View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frameworks

We have successfully created a custom Framework that exposes a callback method in a delegate.  We have created a test application that uses our custom Framework and we can successfully use that callback.  Mow, we want to make a UIView available from our Framework and we do not know how to do this.  This is a new task for us and we have done much research to no avail.

1. Should the code exist in a UIView class instead of the UIViewController class?
2. Should we use awakeFromNib?
3. We just learned about the UINib class?

As you can see, we are getting more confused as we research this topic.  Can anyone out there please give us a clue about how to expose a View from our custom Framework and how to display it from a test application.

Thank you.

Comment: "We just learned about the UINib class?" I don't know the answer to that question, surely you do? :)

Comment: A UIViewController is used to control and deal with a UIView. Depending on the complexity of the view your framework needs to expose, you could use either a UIViewController subclass or a UIView directly. Can't tell you which until you tell us how complicated the view is, and what sort of things it needs to handle.

Comment: @occulus - Thank you for your info.  I know my questions sound confusing as I am completely confused.  It seems the more I research the less I know.  We were having problems with the xib file in the test app.  However, I think we may have gotten past that problem.  Not sure what fixed it, it's just fixed.  Still unable to display the view  but the last error was it couldn't find one of the .png files, so we might have it working soon.  After two days of research and frustration, I just got tired of banking my head against the wall to no avail.